# How to write dynamic delete query in liferay that will delete selected values from a row of data in a table

Tags: liferay-6, dynamic-queries

I want to write a dynamic query which will delete values from a row those will be supplied, i.e a row contains lets say 6 elements i want to delete only 3 of them.How i can achieve that using liferay dynamic query.I am creating a book database and and this my table,I have added picture here. [image]

Now i want to delete description and authorname from second row lets say.How i can do that???Previously i was doing by this

```
long bookId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "bookId");
BookLocalServiceUtil.deleteBook(bookId);
SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "deleted-book"); 
_log.info("#################Book Deleted Successfully#########################");
```

Lets assume that bookName,description etc i can supply inside the delete method.

Answer (score 0):

The only and best way to perform what you want to is to update your entity. For doing so, you have to first retrieve the entity using a `DynamicQuery` and then to update it using the persistence layer.

If you have the bookId and it is your only criterion, you can also use the persistence layer directly to retrieve a bean of your entity.

For your purpose, I think the following is a good solution, in your `BookLocalServiceImpl`:

```
public void updateDescription(long bookId, String description) throws SystemException {
    Book updateMe = bookPersistence.fetchByPrimaryKey(bookId);
    updateMe.setDescription(description);
    bookPersistence.update(updateMe);
}
```

Then in your controller simply call `BookLocalServiceUtil.updateDescription("")` and voila, you just cleared the description.